# How to prevent VC++ 9 linker from linking unnecessary global variables?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, linker

I'm playing with [function-level linking](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xsa71f43(VS.80).aspx) in VC++. I've enabled [/OPT:REF and /OPT:ICF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bxwfs976(VS.80).aspx) and the linker is happy to eliminate all unused functions. Not so with variables.

The following code is to demonstrate the problem only, I fully understand that actually having code structured that way is suboptimal.

```
//A.cpp
SomeType variable1;

//B.cpp
extern SomeType variable1;
SomeType variable2;
class ClassInB {
 //actually uses variable1
};

//C.cpp
extern SomeType variable2;
class ClassInC {
 //actually uses variable2;
};
```

All those files are compiled into a static lib. The consumer project only uses `ClassInC` and links to the static library. Now comes the VC++ 9 linker.

First the linker sees that `C.obj` references `variable2` and includes `B.obj`. `B.obj` references `variable1`, so it includes `A.obj`. Then the unreferenced stuff elimination phase starts. It removes all functions in `A.obj` and `B.obj`, but not the variables. Both `variable` and `variable2` are preserved together with their static initializers and deinitializers. That inflates the image size and introduces a delay for running the initializers and deinitializes.

The code above is oversimplified, in actual code I really can't move `variable2` into `C.cpp` easily. I could put it into a separate .cpp file, but that looks really dumb. Is there any better option to resolve the problem with Visual C++ 9?

Comment: I don't have an answer.... But... does it make a difference if the global variables are turned into static class members? Or, if you want to get rid of the ctor/dtor code, store them as a shared_ptr to a base type?

Answer (score 2):

The [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bxwfs976.aspx) (see the `Arguments` section, `REF | NOREF` arguments, 4th paragraph) specifies that `You have to explicitly mark data as a COMDAT; use __declspec(selectany).` for the linker to remove said unused data when using `/OPT:REF`.

Have you tried and had any chance with [__declspec(selectany)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5tkz6s71.aspx) ?