# Does splitting C++ code into multiple translation units introduce overhead on the executable size?

Tags: c++, linker

I have some code shared among multiple projects in a static library. Even with function-level linking I get more object code than I'd like to in the output - [see another question about that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369515/how-to-prevent-vc-9-linker-from-linking-unnecessary-global-variables).

Surely the most straightforward solution to decreasing the amount of object code linked into the final executable  would be to split the translation units so that I get more .obj files each with less object code. I can even go to extremes -  put each function into a separate translation unit.

Let's pretend I don't care of the mess induced by having ten times more .cpp files and I don't care of possible link time growth.

Will such splitting into many object files introduce overhead on the executable size? Will the executable become bigger simply because there were ten times more .obj files (but overall they have exactly the same functions and variables) linked into it?

Comment: How big are your functions? In extreme cases, a call to a function is bigger than the function would be inlined, because of caller-saves registers and whatnot.

Comment: I hope you have already tried the "strip" command and the compile optimization options. See for example, http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Reducing_Executable_Size

Comment: @zebrabox: Win32 Visual C++ 9. Does it really matter?

Comment: @sharptooth. Dead stripping can reduce overall exe size a lot but seems to vary a lot across linkers i.e vanilla gcc will dead-strip but often won't dead-strip virtual function calls. Not sure what VC++ 9 does

Comment: Though I realise that doesn't really answer your question though! I've definitely heard about this technique being used i.e PlayStation 1's c runtime libs had one func per translation unit but I've never done it myself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Things which are more likely to affect your final EXE size (not exhaustive list):

- Whether you static or dynamically link to libraries (dynamic link is smaller since the library code is not inside your EXE)
- It's possible use of many template classes eg. vector<A>, vector<B>, vector<C> will cause code bloat, since each instantiation of vector with different types is compiled separately
- Compiler settings, eg. optimisation, size vs. speed, inlining (lots of inlining can make code larger), whole program optimisation if supported
- Linker settings, eg. if supported, removing redundant or identical data.  Can help reduce size.

In short splitting code up in to more translation units probably will have no effect - same code, just reorganised.  It might even make things worse if your compiler does not take in to account whole program optimisation, since each translation unit has less information about your program in it.

Answer (score 2):

I think, with modern compilers the output size wins will be too subtle. As far as I know, the compilers only use those functions which are referenced in your code. Other functions and symbols are skipped from the output file.

Comment: See the other question linked to from this question - not having the sources splitted properly can lead to hundreds unused global variables linked to the executable.

Answer (score 1):

No.  I think what you need is to either recompile your static library as a shared library, or use something like: [strip -g -s -R .comment](http://sourceware.org/binutils/docs-2.20/binutils/strip.html#strip) to remove code that is not being used.