# Remove unreferenced global variables from statically linked libraries

Tags: c++

I have a global class the equivalent of this:

```
class CUnref
{
public:
    CUnref() : a(42), b(999)
    {
    }
    virtual ~CUnref()
    {
    }
    int a, b;
};
CUnref Unref;
```

I *want* the global variable `Unref` to be removed from the final executable if it is not referenced.

In my specific case I have a collection of such global helpers to assist in enum<->string conversion in a separate statically linked library. [This stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1229430/how-do-i-prevent-my-unused-global-variables-being-compiled-out)'s answers seem to indicate that these unused global instances should not be linked in the final executable in the specific case of statically linked libraries. Inspecting the generated executable shows the instance and related symbols are still present..

Removing the virtual functions makes it disappear from the final executable (basically making the global unreferenced class POD) but I really need inheritance. I do not perform any side effects (such as allocating memory) or anything, just inheritance.

How do I make sure these unreferenced global variables (of non-POD type but without side effects) are not linked in the final executable?

Compiler is whatever comes with visual studio 2012.

Comment: What are the unused objects supposed to accomplish here? Please expand a bit more on what this (base?) class is used for. As it stands, the code makes little sense and I don't see where this goes. Besides, against the probably *much* more code/data used by the rest of the program, the overhead of a few such garbage objects shouldn't be relevant.

Comment: Don't declare/define global variables in header files!

Comment: I've clarified the main post to be more explicit about what I want to achieve.

Comment: Just now stackoverflow suggested [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369515/how-to-prevent-vc-9-linker-from-linking-unnecessary-global-variables?rq=1) in the sidebar (it didn't do so when I was writing it) providing a solution which worked, marking the globals with `__declspec(selectany)` makes the linker remove the unreferenced variables (and related functions). Since this question is 'on hold' I can't close this though...

Comment: @πάντα-ῥεῖ Unless they're templates!

Comment: @MichaelGazonda You're correct (just a bit late). Anyway a template never was in question here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution provided by [How to prevent VC++ 9 linker from linking unnecessary global variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369515/how-to-prevent-vc-9-linker-from-linking-unnecessary-global-variables?rq=1)

In msvc mark the globals with `__declspec(selectany)` will make the linker remove them if they are unreferenced.